# Problema con botón que almacene valor en tiempo real en base de datos

Tags: javascript, php

Hola gente estoy trabajando en un proyecto de foro entre usuarios que se actualiza en tiempo real.
Mi problema está en la implementación de un botón para dar positivo al comentario, no ejecuta ninguna acción, sospecho que es porque formulario de envío de variables se encuentra dentro del mismo main.js. Soy nuevo en esto de JS y no he encontrado una forma de que funcione o programar el chat de otra manera.

main.js

```
var myVar = setInterval(LoadData, 2000);

http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

function LoadData(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'view.php',
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#MyTable div').empty();
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      var commentId = data[i].iddisc;
      if(data[i].parent_comment == 0){

        var date = new Date(data[i].datePubli);
        var hourCycle = date.toLocaleString('es-ES', {hourCycle: 'h23' });

//AL FINAL DE LA SIGUIENTE LÍNEA SE ENCUENTRA EL DESARROLLO DEL BOTÓN POSITIVO

    

        var row = $('<div class="info-box"><img src="./css/escudos/' + data[i].equipo + '.png" width="25px" height="25px" /><p>' + data[i].username + '</p><p id="date-p"> '+ hourCycle +'</p></div><div class="text-box"><p>' + data[i].post + '</p><div class="reply"><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="'+ commentId +'" title="Responder comentario" class="open-ReplyModal" href="#ReplyModal"><img src="./css/responder.png" width="20" height="20"></a></div><div class="bttn-pos"><form name="positiv" method="post"><input type="hidden" class="form-pos" name="pos" value="' + data[i].iddisc + '"><input type="button" id="positivo" name="positivo" class="suma" value="+"></form></div></div>');
        $('#record').append(row);              
      }
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
  }
 });
}


//Paso data
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#positivo').on('click', function() {
        $("#positivo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var posi = document.forms["positiv"]["pos"].value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "positivo.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    posi: posi,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==300){
                        alert("Funciona");
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Archivo positivo.php

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

$idchat=$_POST['posi'];


$votar=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chatvoto (id_chat,idvoto,voto) VALUES (:id_chat,0,1)");
$votar->bindParam(':id_chat',$idchat);
$votar->execute();


echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>300));       

 ?>
```

En el archivo view.php muestro los comentarios del chat

```
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT *, discussion.id as iddisc, users.id as usersid FROM discussion INNER JOIN users ON discussion.id_user=users.id ORDER BY discussion.id desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch()){
  array_push($data, $row);
  array_push($data);
        
}

echo json_encode($data);
$conn = null;
exit();
```

Disculpen si es mucho código por analizar pero hace días hago diferentes pruebas y no sé como solucionar esto.

Comment: Hola Marcos, esta hardcodeado en `value="31"` (_imagino que deberías concatenar algun valor sacado de `data[i]`_)

Comment: Hola, si, no me había dado cuenta, lo había cambiado para hacer una prueba. Ya lo edité en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el problema podría deberse a que estas asignando el evento click a positivo en el $(document).ready() pero eso se crea dinámicamente después de que el documento esté listo.

Aquí te dejo una posible solución.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#positivo', function() {
        $("#positivo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var posi = document.forms["positiv"]["pos"].value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "positivo.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    posi: posi,
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataResult){
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
                    if(dataResult.statusCode==300){
                        alert("Funciona");
                    }
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Aaah claro tiene sentido, lo corregí y funcionó muchas gracias!

Comment: dale el voto a  la respuesta si te es útil también.